# "More than 1 Couchbase environment" warning as misconfiguration, why?

Tags: rx-java, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I’ve tried to google and search around forum for more convincing answers on this topic.
The below are what i’ve found:

1. [Scalability and Concurrency](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/java/managing-connections.html#concept2677__concurrency)
2. [More than 1 Couchbase Environments found](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/more-than-1-couchbase-environments-found/2434/3)
3. [Getting out of memory exception while creating multiple couchbase Environments](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/getting-out-of-memory-exception-while-creating-multiple-couchbase-environments/3585/2)

Yet, I still do not understand what are the actual “unpredictable behaviors” and “resources” the answers above are referring to. Can anyone help to give a more detail explanation please?

Let's assume I’m using Java SDK with [`DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment`](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.0.0/com/couchbase/client/java/env/DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.html) builder, if I build two environments with different timeout/kvendpoints/other parameters, how would one affecting another? Is there any static shared module in the environment?

Would this be somehow related to the RxJava compute scheduler / io?